# How can I hide #! on browser address bar?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mod-rewrite, browser

Let's say I have the following link:

```
www.blahblah.com/#!?page=index
```

How can I convert it to one of the following:

- `www.blahblah.com/#!/index` (this one should be made with mod_rewrite)
- `www.blahblah.com/ajax/index` (still mod_rewrite, but #! replaced with ajax)
- `www.blahblah.com/index` (the page will load with AJAX like facebook, but #! will be hidden)

Can anyone give me examples of each of the questions above?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Come on guys, this isn't that bad a question, even though the premise of using mod_rewrite is flawed. Look closely

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?

Comment: The thingy after the `#` octothorpe is called the path fragment. Neither the server nor mod_rewrite will ever see it. It must be handled client-side.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: Really? He wants the first URL he gave to be displayed differently in the address bar. I had no problems understand what he wants to do; I'm just not sure what the best practice in this case is.

Comment: When you load a URL like `www.blahblah.com/#!?page=index` the browser is going to send a request for `www.blahblah.com/` to the server. It will not send anything after the hash, so you can't touch it with PHP or mod_rewrite. Your only real option is to use javascript to process the hash, and do a redirect to some other URL. But javascript is unreliable and slow. Basically, you should avoid using # in the URL at all, unless it's for something trivial (like scrolling to a specific point on a page, or activating a specific "tab" somewhere on the page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything after the hash (`#`) isn't sent to the server, so you cannot read it server-side. You can, however, redirect the user using JavaScript. The information you're looking for will be stored in the variable `window.location.hash`.

On page load, you can do something like the following:

```
hashString = window.location.hash.substring(8);
window.location = 'http://www.blahblah.com/'+hashString;
```

We're using `substring` to remove the first eight characters (`#!?page=`), so we'll be left with `index`.

Answer (score 1):

Module rewrite only changes what the server sees. Module rewrite can't, change what the local browser sees, which is where the js is being run.

The way Facebook load, is through requesting the contents of the new page, then it updates the window URL instead of having to re-load everything. This is done, so If an item needs to be shared or linked the link is all up to date with what they're actually viewing, so when the page gets a fresh re-load, the browser loads the actual full php page, requested from the server.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden # in a ajax page loading strategy is done by HTML 5 pushState.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use `window.location.hash` for this.